# Resolving promises within a foreach statement

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to resolve multiple promises and return something when all of them have resolved

I've looked around but can't find a solution or I'm just not understanding.

My Code:

```
export const setLeagues = (res: any, leaguesArray: any) => {
leaguesArray.forEach((element: any) => {
    firebaseAdmin.firestore().collection('leagues').add(element)
        .catch((err: any) => { res.send(err) })
})
```

}

I want to do a `res.send('Successfully Added!)` when all promises in the forEach has resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple enough if you use `Promise.all` and `map`:

```
export const setLeagues = (res: any, leaguesArray: any) => {
    // Wrap in a Promise.all, and use .map instead of .forEach:
    Promise.all(leaguesArray.map((element: any) => {
        // Make sure to return promise here...
        return firebaseAdmin.firestore().collection('leagues').add(element)
            .catch((err: any) => { res.send(err) })
    })).then(() => {
        // Do things here that need to wait for all promises to resolve.
    })
}
```

---

I'll note that due to the way `Promise.all` works, you may want to change the way you handle an error as well. `Promise.all` rejects as soon as any of it's wrapped promises reject, or resolves when all of its wrapped promises resolve. So I would recommend moving your `.catch` to chain off the `Promise.all` rather than the inner promises to avoid sending a response twice:

```
export const setLeagues = (res: any, leaguesArray: any) => {
    // Wrap in a Promise.all, and use .map instead of .forEach:
    Promise.all(leaguesArray.map((element: any) => {
        // Make sure to return promise here...
        return firebaseAdmin.firestore().collection('leagues').add(element)
    })).then(() => {
        // Do things here that need to wait for all promises to resolve.
        res.send('Successfully Added!')
    }).catch((err: any) => {
        // Consider moving error handler to here instead...
        res.send(err)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to collect all your promises into and array and use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to generate a new promise that's resolved only after each one of them is resolved.  The general form is like this:

```
const promises = []
things.forEach(thing => {
    promises.push(createPromiseForWork(thing))
})
const p = Promise.all(promises)
p.then(() => {
    // continue with your work
})
```