# I cant get the result out of a fulfilled Promise React

Tags: javascript, promise

**Hello everyone**

**My goal**:

Get the result out of a Promise that is fullfilled to use the result in a other piece of code

**the results that I get are:**

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5K2v.png)

but the expected result is the [[PromiseResult]].

I tried other methods I found on here. but there was one problem I did get the result only to show up in the command.log but when I tried to assign it to a value it looked like it skipped right over the code. I know this sounds like a duplicate posts of a post of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/16825593#16825593) but I tried it and it didn't work for me.

**the check boundries returns a Promise**

```
function getData() {
    setLoading(true);
    ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const items = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
         let itemurl = 'http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png';
        let item = doc.data()
        
        
        console.log(checkBoundaries(doc.data().RawData))
        itemurl =  checkBoundaries(doc.data().RawData)
      console.log( itemurl)
      item.colorIcon = itemurl;
        console.log(item)
        items.push(item);
        console.log(items)

      });
      setRuuviTag(items);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }
```

but i cant get item.colorIcon to become the promise result

it would help alot if anyone knew a fix for this

**Update**

```
async function checkBoundaries(rdata) {
   let iconurl;
    try {
      const response = await PostRawData(rdata)
      
      const data = response.data
      if (22.00>data.temperature && data.temperature > 4.00) {
        console.log('if')
        iconurl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-blue.png'
      }
      else {
        console.log('else')
        iconurl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-red.png'
      }
      } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
      }
      console.log(`this is the url ${iconurl}`)
     
      return iconurl
     
      // ...
    }
```

I will now get the things i tried but wont work

Comment: You need to show us the definition of the `checkBoundaries` which is causing the problem. And yes, it sounds very much like a duplicate, so please explain in detail how you tried the approaches from the answers there.

Comment: if `checkBoundaries(doc.data().RawData)` returns a Promise, then `itemurl` will, naturally, be a Promise ... use async/await or the standard Promise `.then` method

Comment: You'll want to collect into an array the promises that you get from calling `checkBoundaries` in the `forEach` on the snapshot, and use `Promise.all`

Comment: i think the problem is that its in a firebase function i cant make a sync or something so it wont wait on the outcome

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39151939/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/35879695/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/48432930/1048572